# Union with one different column

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I would like to use UNION to connect two views (view CSP contains 1 more column so I want to use * for 2nd in case of some items from 2nd view are not in 1st view) and that's working good but I have no duplicated configuration id either with right value and with *.

How to solve that and remove lines with '*' when there is value in csp?

```
SELECT csp.customer_no,
       csp.contract,
       csp.customer_part_no,
       csp.configuration_id,
       csp.catalog_no
FROM customersomething csp
UNION
SELECT spc.customer_no,
       spc.contract,
       spc.customer_part_no,
       '*' AS "configuration_id",
       spc.catalog_no
FROM
superproduct spc

+-------------+----------+-----+------------------+--------+
| customer_no | contract | ... | configuration_id |        |
+-------------+----------+-----+------------------+--------+
|          17 | whatever | ... | *                | view A |
|          17 | whatever | ... | right_one        | view B |
+-------------+----------+-----+------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `union all` unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Second, filter out the second one.  Here is a way using `not exists`:

```
SELECT csp.customer_no, csp.contract, csp.customer_part_no,
       csp.configuration_id, csp.catalog_no
FROM customersomething csp
UNION ALL
SELECT spc.customer_no, spc.contract, spc.customer_part_no,
       '*' AS "configuration_id", spc.catalog_no
FROM superproduct spc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM customersomething csp
                  WHERE scp.customer_no = spc.customer_no
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this query,

```
SELECT spc.customer_no,
   spc.contract,
   spc.customer_part_no,
   csp.configuration_id,
   spc.catalog_no FROM superproduct spc
   LEFT JOIN customersomething csp ON spc.customer_no = csp.customer_no
   UNION ALL
   SELECT csp.customer_no,
   csp.contract,
   csp.customer_part_no,
   csp.configuration_id,
   csp.catalog_no
   FROM customersomething csp
   LEFT JOIN  superproduct spc ON spc.customer_no = csp.customer_no AND spc.customer_no IS NULL
```